# GuzzleHttp error parameter contain slashes

Tags: php, parameters, guzzle, slash

I have a problem using GuzzleHttp in Laravel.

I'm making a GET call to a route with a parameter that contains slashes. So the road does not exist.

How can I make it take that as a single parameter?

Thank you for your answers !

I tried escaping the character, encoding it, adding backslashes but nothing worked.

Comment: have you tried escaping it using `urlencode` ?

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.